# How to build page with pattern-like elements

Tags: php, html

I want create sort of quiz. But questions will be different, depend on what options were selected in drop-down menu.

Main problem is where I need to store my html blocks with questions?
All questions will be like this pattern:

```
<tr>
<td>Question</td>
<td>Answer 1, Answer 2, ...</td>
</tr>
```

Total amount of questions - 50, full "question-table" have 10 questions and submit button.
Total amount of different combinations - over 100 "question-tables".
Question in most cases will be repeated.

At first, I try to store my questions in variables:

```
$question01 = '<tr>
<td>Question 01</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="v2" checked="" >Answer 1 <input type="radio" name="v2">Answer 2</td>
</tr>';
```

And then I compose them in table, like:

```
$fullTable = $question01 . $question02 . $question03;
```

But I don't feel right about this. Maybe you can at least point at which framework/pattern I should look? 
Examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: put answers in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your html blocks in variables right inside your script, but that's not necessarily the most maintainable route.  I like to use a templating engine, where your HTML is stored in a separate file with special placeholders that the PHP script will fill in.  Personally, I'm a fan of [MiniTemplator](http://www.source-code.biz/MiniTemplator/).  It supports defining blocks of HTML you can repeat over and over with different substitutions each time.

For example, using MiniTemplator syntax, your HTML would look like this:

```
    <!-- $beginBlock Question -->
    <tr>
     <td>{$question_text}</td>
     <td>{$answer_options}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- $endBlock Question -->
```

Then, in your code, you'd call routines on the MiniTemplator class like so (probably in a loop over all question/answer sets).  Where $t is an instance of the MiniTemplator class and has your template loaded:

```
$t->setVariable("question_text", "What is your name?");
$t->setVariable("answer_options", "A: Pudnintame, B: Murgatroyd, C: Ethyl");
$t->addBlock("Question");
```

Each time those three lines are executed (with different questions and answer options filled in), the templating engine will add another block of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

i can translate it to PHP for you if you like but you should have something like:

```
 question = {id:"123", question:"", answers:[{text:"",id:"2"}], correct:"2"}
```

then you can iterate over all questions and populate the possible answers from an array...  When they submit an answer, you can look up the correct answer on the id

```
$ans = $_POST['ans'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
if ($ans == $question[$id]['correct'] )
{
   echo "correct!";
}
```

storing on the client though, you most likely wouldnt want it to be displayed none.  I would agree that if you have a script that makes a question answer pairs, then you would just call the php script as needed.  something like:

```
for (var i = 10;i;i--){
    //calls 10 times
    $.ajax("mygenscript.php", function(){  
         //replace previous question block with this new question.
    });
}
```

then you arent storing things on the client side.

could then have something like:

and in the success call say:

```
var newQ = "result from ajax call"; 
$("div#question").empty().append(newQ);
```

Comment: The OP is asking about where to store the HTML, not just the question/answer key.

Comment: standby, let me adjust. Thank you